# Maximum number of consecutive 1 in a given number

Tags: java, binary, decimal

```
public int tobinary(int x)
{
    int count = 0;
    while(x!=0)
    {
        x=(x&(x<<1));         //how this stuff is working
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

the above code is working fine but actually i did copy and paste.so i just want to know how that line of code which i mentioned above is working.it would be a great help for me.

> for example i am giving i/p as 7 the binary format for this is 0111 so our answer will be 3 but how ?

Comment: For a start, the method name is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

As we know, the `<<` operator shifts all bits in its operand to the left, here by 1.  Also, the `&` operator performs a bitwise-and on all bits of both its operands.

When will `x` not be `0`?  When the bitwise-and operation finds 2 bits that are both set in both operands. The only time that this will be true is when there are 2 or more consecutive `1` bits in `x` and `x << 1`.

```
x     : 0000 0111
x << 1: 0000 1110
-----------------
     &: 0000 0110
count = 1
```

If it's not `0`, then there are at least 2 consecutive `1` bits in the number, and the (maximum) number of consecutive `1` bits in the number has been reduced by 1.  Because we entered the loop in the first place, count it and try again.  Eventually there won't be any more consecutive `1` bits, so we exit the loop with the correct count.

```
x     : 0000 0110
x << 1: 0000 1100
-----------------
     &: 0000 0100
count = 2

x     : 0000 0100
x << 1: 0000 1000
-----------------
     &: 0000 0000
count = 3, exit loop and return.
```

Answer (score 1):

`x = (x & (x << 1))` is performed enough times to eliminate the longest consecutive groups of `1` bits. Each loop iteration reduces each consecutive group of `1`s by one because the number is logically `AND`ed with itself shifted left by one bit. This continues until no consecutive group of `1`s remains.

To illustrate it for number `110111101`:

```
 110111101 // initial x, longest sequence 4
1101111010 // x << 1, count 1
 100111000 // new x, longest sequence 3
1001110000 // x << 1, count 2
    110000 // new x, longest sequence 2
   1100000 // x << 1, count 3
    100000 // new x, longest sequence 1
   1000000 // x << 1, count 4
         0 // new x, end of loop
```

Do note that since Java 7 it's handy to declare binary literals with `int input = 0b110111101`.

Answer (score 0):

> > **<< (left shift)**  : Binary Left Shift Operator. The left operands value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

i.e. `x<<1` shifts the value bit from right to left by 1 and in the unit position add `0`. So, lets say for `x=7`, bit representation will be `111`. Performing `x << 1` will return `110` i.e. discarded the head element, shifted the bits to left and added `0` in the end.

This while loop can be broken down into below iteration for initial value of `x=7`

iteration 1) `111 & 110  =110`

iteration 2) `110 & 100  =100`

iteration 3) `100 & 000  =000`

As value of `x` is 0, no more iteration

Hope this explains the behaviour of this code. You can put `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));` to see the change in bit value of `x` yourself

Answer (score 0):

So what happens is, for each iteration in the while loop, 
x = x (AND operator) (2 * x).

For example, when x = 7
count = 0

```
Iteration 1:

//x = 7 & 14 which results in 6 ie

0111
1110 (AND)
-------
0110 => 6
-------
count = 1

Iteration 2:

//x = 6 & 12 results in 4

0110
1100 AND
-------
0100 => 4
-------
count = 2

Iteration 3:
// x = 4 & 8 results in 0

0100
1000 AND
-----
0000 
-----
count = 3
```

That's how you get 3 for 7